# What's the name of this Component in winform VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, ado.net, poco

What's the name of  this Component in winform VS2010?

[image]

Comment: http://i40.tinypic.com/90v9dy.png

Comment: Looks like a datagridview though hard to be 100% sure - can't you just view it's properties in the designer?

Comment: Having some data in the control would make it a lot clearer.  It is not quite a ListView with View = Details, more likely a custom grid control.  Every component vendor sells one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the `DataGridView` to me.

Comment: The Name Of This Component in WinForm Please?
Can you help me 

<a href="http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9XqP.png">ici</a>

Comment: I try with dataGridView .ِcan you give me another